# Facing this error when i upload laraval app to live server

Tags: laravel, httpclient, server-error

**This error occur when i trying to hit api from live server.But locally api running correctly. I got this error**

```
cURL error 28: Failed to connect to testapi.certccie.com port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Here we uploaded error image [image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKUZn.png

Comment: You're probably being firewalled or something similar. Reach out to the hosting  API provider or contact your hosting provider to get relevant details. No one here can help you with that little information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of your host that your host dont access to certccie.com.

Try on another host.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. this should be a comment. please don't post comment as an answer.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I faced this error before and this is the exact answer.

Comment: sorry but `may be`  and `try` is not acceptable as answer. an answer should be 100% sure about what op is looking for. consider updating your answer if you want to post it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Ahsanfarooq yes another host that you sure some domains not banned on that for example european hosts that domain not banned in that countries.

Comment: If we run our api on our local server it is displaying data correctly but when we shit our laravel on a live server is displaying issue. This error ocuured

cURL error 28: Failed to connect to testapi.certccie.com port 443: Connection timed out


when we have a conversation with laraval host regarding our issue i am sending you their responce regarding our problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience. The telnet is also not working: telnet testapi.certccie.com 443
Trying 198.38.83.246...
telnet: connect to address 198.38.83.246: Connection timed out

The telnet is failing means, either you are blocking our connection or there is an issue with your server.

Comment: This is the main issue if you understand this problem kindly help to solve

Comment: @Ahsanfarooq if telnet is also not working means that your the problem is from your host.

Comment: @Ahsanfarooq could you test your app in another host?